# How to describe data changes over time?

Tags: time

I have a dataset, it has the problem that data changes overtime.

[image]

In the pic above, the distribution is plotted every 5 years, and it could be seen that the distribution is not constant, it changes over time?

How should I describe it? I used to call it `time shift`, but it seems not very proper? I need a short title to put it in a sub-title in my paper.

Comment: "Change in [Noun] over Time"

Comment: I agree with @ringo that labeling it change over or though time is the best approach if it is the change you wish to focus on. However, I see remarkable underlying stability such that a model derived from among all the "blue" data or all the "green" data would be fairly accurate in predicting the next instance. But I think in biological terms.

Comment: @ringo, the left is speed, and the right is direction distribution. I'm afraid that `Change in speed and direction over time` is a bit long for a title. Additionally, should I say `over time`, `across time`?

Comment: The data is variable (or "dynamic" or "not static") with respect to time.

Comment: @HotLicks, is there any way I can make this into a short title?

Comment: Do you want it to be short or be understood?

Comment: Since you are taking different samples of a random variable, you shouldn't expect it to be the same each time. I'd question whether it's appropriate to include such a graph instead of some descriptive statistics trying to characterize the distribution. The left side looks like a poisson or gamma distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can say it is [labile](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=labile) or has lability (readily changing or widely fluctuating). 
Example sentence: **Lability** in the data makes it difficult to pin point stuff.

Comment: Can I say `shift over time`? of simply `time shift`?

Comment: @cqcn1991 "shift over time" is a bit weird. Although not incorrect, it indicates more of a position change as "shift" is used in regards of position. So, "shift change" is a correct phrase, just not that appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it *sound* more technical by saying the "the distribution shows *temporal flux*".

> *temporal* adjective 1. Relating to time
>
> *flux* noun 3. A state of flow or continuous change

(Chambers dictionary: iPhone edition)